# Which method or tool to transform a web site into a design template?

Tags: html, css, templates, web

I would like to perform web test and learning like some makes music by sampling. So, I would like to make a new design by compozing with them and add my touch.

Say I have the html, css, js, etc files from the site owner, I imagine it is possible to automatically build templates and layouts as [HALM](http://haml.info/) and LESS or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) files from them. For example, a html parser may find nested common structures in pages. A css parser may find common constants and replace them by variables.

Does such tool already exists ? Or what could be the cavits to develop one ?

Exemple for CSS:
From:

```
h1 { background-color: #ff14a6; }
h2 { color: #ff14a6; }
```

To:

```
$primary: #ff14a6;
h1 { background-color: $primary; }
h2 { color: $primary; }
```

HTML is formed from: Layout + Template, where *Layout* is the overall structure of the HTML page. Here is a Ruby example:
File: layout.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> ... etc.
</head>
<body>
<%= yield =>
</body>
</html>
```

Template replaces layout's *yield*.

Some layout content is page-specific, while template contains frontmatter. In template (contact.html.erb):

```
---
title: "Contact Information"
---
```

In layout (layout.erb):

```
<title> <%= current_page.data.title %>
</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a template for whatever information you want to display your best bet is a JSON container to hold the new data and your javascript + jquery to import the data to the html.  This could be done with a separate js file for the new data or the same one as the app/web page constructor js file.

This way you could have a set template layout for importing your data and then just change the file if you want to use different data.  Alternatively using a framework like knockoutjs or something similar could allow you to do this as well, depending ofc on what you are familiar with or like to use.

The following snippet is a demo of jQuery using data from a JSON object to place data in the HTML (this would be the script.js file):

```
var view = {
displayStuff: function(obj){
var HTMLwelcomeMsg = '<span class="welcome-message">%data%</span>';
var formattedWelcome = HTMLwelcomeMsg.replace("%data%", obj.welcomeMessage);
$("#header").append(formattedWelcome);
}}
```

The JSON data can be in a separate file loaded by the JS or the HTML:

```
var model = {
"dataSample1" : "Some data",
"welcomeMessage" : "Welcome to the sample website",
"dataSample2" : "Some more data",
"someNumbers" : [1,1,253,669],
"moreVars" : {
"someMoreData" : ["123 31st st", "311 2nd st"],
"phoneNums" : ["555-5555", "999-999"]
}
}
```

Or you can put the data inside the JS file you use to append the elements to the HTML.

Then you call your view from the controller:

```
var controller = function(){
view.displayStuff(model);
}
```

and it all just works.

Comment: Thanks James, but my question is not to know the best tampleting solution - if I understand you correctly. My request is how to build a template and a LESS or SASS CSS factorization from an existing web site. If there exist aleady solutions, or drivers to do so.